# ASP.NET MVC - Is it possible to have a MVC subproject in a FORMS rootproject?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, multiple-inheritance, webforms

I'm trying to find out if other people are able to do this. I've found the following question and answer (which refers to Scott Hanselmans post on mixing Forms and MVC) ([Can I use ASP.NET MVC together with regular ASP.NET Web forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541703/can-i-use-asp-net-mvc-together-with-regular-asp-net-web-forms)). However this is not quite the same.

> **Are you able to run a .NET FORMS project on a server (as rootproject) and at the same time have a MVC running on the same server (as subproject)?** Just try empty default projects, it won't work :)

http://server (or http://www.server.com) --- FORMS PROJECT
http://server/mvc (or http://www.server.com/mvc) --- MVC PROJECT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just configure IIS so that both folders are applications. Though you will probably not be able to use the VS webserver.

Answer (score 0):

That would imply you would want bind 2 (two) IIS sites to the same IP/Port which would create an issue in IIS.  I think instead you should try to run a hybrid project with both and have some handled by WebForms and some handled by MVC.  You could always just split up the MVC project and have data access, business logic and controllers in another project if you want.  If you want to see an example of this there's a link below to the S#arp Architecture which splits an MVC project into many parts.

http://sharparchitecture.net/