# Can I achieve exactly the same user experience with ASP.NET MVC as with ASP.NET (Webforms)?

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I use ASP.NET MVC together with regular ASP.NET Web forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541703/can-i-use-asp-net-mvc-together-with-regular-asp-net-web-forms)

Let's say I need to build a shopping cart. Would I be able to get the same user experience with ASP.NET MVC or would I need to "pick the right tool for the job" - use Webforms and MVC where applicable instead of just focusing on either one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVC is just a different way of using the same tool (in my experience anyways).  Actually... looking back over previous Web Forms projects... I wish I could convert them all to MVC.. the separation is so much better/cleaner.

I agree with @egrunin tho.. same user experience is accomplished through either method of development.. it's just a different way of thinking about things (IE: MVC is stateless).

*As per your edited question*

> you can blend MVC and Web Forms,
>   however I would highly recommend
>   picking one or the other. You'll be
>   thankful for it later.  MVC's learning
>   curve isn't actually all that hard
>   once you dive in.

Answer (score 3):

If by "same result" you mean "same user experience" -- of course.

**Edited to add:** MVC, like all frameworks, started as a way for developers to get the "same result" with less work. Anything that can be done *with* a framework can be done *without* it, it just takes more time. Frameworks reduce work by *excluding* possibilities: a manual transmission can do some things an automatic can't, but it saves you enough effort that you don't mind.

If you're asking if you can use WinForms and MVC simultaneously...you can always drop a plain WinForm into an MVC site.

Answer (score 1):

In the end you're just generating **html** which gets sent to the browser. There it gets a sauce of **css** and behavior due to **javascript** over it.

Generating the html can be done with both Webforms and MVC, or another server side technology.

Comment: MVC **IS** ASP.NET... the difference is Web Forms vs MVC

Comment: I corrected the possible misunderstanding.  
`MVC __IS__ ASP.NET`. Well, not exactly. You have the ASP.NET framework and Webforms, MVC and Dynamic Data are built on top of that. According to some there's also a fourth pillar: ASP.NET Ajax but that's not really agreed upon by everyone.