# hosting ASP.net application inside MVC app

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-config

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I use ASP.NET MVC together with regular ASP.NET Web forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541703/can-i-use-asp-net-mvc-together-with-regular-asp-net-web-forms)

I have an ASP.net MVC 3 application

and and ASP.net app in a subdirectory `/App2`

both are on .net 4,

`web.config` from `/App2/web.config` inherits the one from the root, so in order to make the `App2` work I had to copy all the dlls from `/bin` into `/App2/bin`, even though `App2` doesn't needs them

anybody knows another way to fix this ?

> the applications are built separately, they are just deployed on the
>   hosting server as one, the MVC is the root, and the web-forms inside a
>   subdirectory, and to make it work I have to copy all the
>   System.Web.Mvc.dll etc. in the /bin of the the web-forms app

Comment: [Check out this posts](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&q=mvc+inside+webforms+site%3Astackoverflow.com)

Comment: no it's not duplicate, because I have web forms inside MVC and that's a different thing, and the issue is the web.config inheritance

Comment: There is no difference between WebForms inside MVC, and MVC inside WebForms.