# MVC for ASP.net Webform

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

Goal:
Use MVC with ASP.net Webform only.

Problem statement:
Is it possible to use the concept MVC (Model, View etc.) for ASP.NET webform? If yes, how do I do it? Got any picture?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541703/can-i-use-asp-net-mvc-together-with-regular-asp-net-web-forms

Comment: Yes. Ofcourse, thats why ASP.Net team created a framework MVC and removed the code behind and clean seperation. If you still like to mess up MVC with webform you can create your own and do

Comment: You might be interested in MVP, a framework with the same goals as MVC: http://webformsmvp.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be some confusion in the comments.  If I understand you correctly, you are not trying to make Webforms work with the ASP.NET MVC technology.  You want to use the MVC Pattern with a WebForms page.

If that's the case, then no.  You can't use the MVC Pattern with a Webforms page (ie full page lifecycle, etc..).  The WebForms model just doesn't work in a way that is consistent with an MVC design.

You can, however, use other patterns that are similar to MVC and try to achieve similar goals of separation of concerns.  The most common of these is the MVP or Model View Presenter pattern.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93presenter

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188690.aspx

Comment: "There seems to be some confusion in the comments. If I understand you correctly, you are not trying to make Webforms work with the ASP.NET MVC technology. You want to use the MVC Pattern with a WebForms page." YES, that is correct!

Comment: @Legato - Then the information in my answer is correct.